# BS4 Web scraper: Iterated list skips first value after being appended(only when list is emailed, not printed)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, smtplib

I'm sure this has been asked, however, I have not found a solution thus far that matches my specific case. As this is my first Python project, I am having a good bit of trouble fixing this issue, as it is not always present.

The problem I am having is that even though my iterated list prints the articles I have scraped correctly, when I join the list to another list to email it, occasionally, it skips the first string in the list. Even if I plug a random value into the second list to "fake" a value for it to skip, it will still skip the first article I would like emailed as well as the "fake" value. Where am I making a mistake at?

```
import smtplib
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/section/technology')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find("body")
arr1 = []

for h in body.findAll("h2", {"class" : "headline"} ):
 arr1.append(h.text.strip())

print( "The articles below were curated from The New York Times Technology 
section: ")
print(" ")

list1 = []

for item in arr1[:10]:
    print(item)
    list1.append("-" + item +'\n')

print_it = input("Would you like to send an email? Yes or no. ")
if print_it.lower() == 'yes':
#encodes to unicode and prevents it from causing problems       
    trial = u''.join(list1).encode('utf-8').strip()     
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("senderemail@email.com", "PASSWORD")
    msg = (trial)
    server.sendmail("senderemail@email.com", "recipientemail@email.com", msg)
    server.quit()  
    os.system('cls')
    print("Email has been sent.")

else:
    os.system('cls')
    print("No email has been sent!")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the mail that you receive where the data is missing? While printing the data in `list1` and even in `'trial` it seems to me intact.

Comment: Currently, the email I receive lists these articles(shortened for character limit):

-How Mark Zuckerberg Became Too Big to Fail
-Start-Ups Ask, ‘Are We Making Money for Saudi Arabia?’
-A Cryptocurrency Millionaire Wants to Build
-How to Buy a Used Phone 
-Spotting Disinformation Online 
-How to Find the Video Games
-Just Embed a Phone 
-Apple iPhone XR Review
-Apple Raises Prices

However, I am missing "Google Walkout: Employees Stage Protest Over Handling of Sexual Harassment", which is the first article on the page, as seen here https://www.nytimes.com/section/technology

Comment: what do you mean by _occasionally, it skips the first string_ I could not replicate the scenario that you are mentioning here.